# Remove a specific function from theme parent Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, parent-child, meta-boxes

I try to remove a "meta_box" action from the parent theme function.php, but I don't succeed.

I already tried many function, but i think i don't doing well. Here, some functions that i tried to apply:

```
if (!function_exists('add_meta_box')) {
function add_meta_box() {add_meta_box( 'portfolio-meta-boxes', __('Portfolio Options','raw'), 'child_display_portfolio_meta_box', 'udt_portfolio', 'normal', 'high' );
}
}
function child_display_portfolio_meta_box() {...}
```

Or

```
add-action('after_theme_setup', 'remove_fonction_parent');
function remove_fonction_parent() {
function remove_fonction_parent() {
remove_meta_box('page_layout','display_portfolio_meta_box');
add_meta_box('page_layout','child_display_portfolio_meta_box');
}
function child_display_portfolio_meta_box() {...}
```

And some other ways but unfortunately, that doesn't work...

I want to replace the function who call the 3 "templates" (Default, Full Width Featured Media, Without Featured Media) by my one function and my 2 templates.

Here the code i want to remove/change, especially the part who calling the page layout :

```
function create_portfolio_meta_box() {
global $key_portfolio; 
if( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' ) ) {
    add_meta_box( 'portfolio-meta-boxes', __('Portfolio Options','raw'), 'display_portfolio_meta_box', 'udt_portfolio', 'normal', 'high' );
}
}

function display_portfolio_meta_box() {
    global $post, $meta_boxes_portfolio, $key_portfolio;
?>
<div class="form-wrap">
    <?php
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), $key_portfolio . '_wpnonce', false, true );
    foreach($meta_boxes_portfolio as $meta_box) {
        $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key_portfolio, true);
        ?>
        <?php if($meta_box[ 'name' ]=='display_title') { ?>
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>"><?php echo $meta_box[ 'title' ]; ?></label>
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" name="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ])) { echo htmlspecialchars( $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] ); } ?>" />
                <p><?php echo $meta_box[ 'description' ]; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php } else if($meta_box[ 'name' ]=='teaser') {?>
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>"><?php echo $meta_box[ 'title' ]; ?></label>
                <textarea id="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" name="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>"><?php if(isset($data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ])) { echo htmlspecialchars( $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] ); } ?></textarea>
                <p><?php echo $meta_box[ 'description' ]; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php } else if($meta_box[ 'name' ]=='page_layout') { ?>
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>"><?php echo $meta_box[ 'title' ]; ?></label>
                <select id="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" name="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" style="min-width:200px;">
                    <option value="default" <?php if(isset($data[$meta_box['name']])) selected($data[$meta_box['name']],'default'); ?>>Default</option>
                    <option value="full-width-media" <?php if(isset($data[$meta_box['name']])) selected($data[$meta_box['name']],'full-width-media'); ?>>Full Width Featured Media</option>
                    <option value="without-featured-media" <?php if(isset($data[$meta_box['name']])) selected($data[$meta_box['name']],'without-featured-media'); ?>>Without Featured Media</option>
                </select>
                <p><?php echo $meta_box[ 'description' ]; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php } else if($meta_box[ 'name' ]=='display_media_caption') { ?>
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>"><?php echo $meta_box[ 'title' ]; ?></label>
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" name="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ])) { echo htmlspecialchars( $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] ); } ?>" />
                <p><?php echo $meta_box[ 'description' ]; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }?>
</div>
```

Could someone explain me what is wrong with my tests and help me find a solution?

Thank you very much and sorry for my "not so good" English :)

Answer (score 0):

This Tutorial helped me to remove a metabox from a WP theme:

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-modify-the-parent-theme-behavior-within-the-child-theme--wp-31006

Hope it helps in your case.

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.